# PostgreSQL JSONB Index for matching exact int key

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-performance, jsonb

I have a table with column "times" that contain simple object `{ key(int): value(int), ... }`

```
{
    1: 100,
    2: 200,
    3: 200,
    ...
}
```

Keys are static for each instance, values are dynamic.

Sometimes, I need to order 50 000 instances by value of one specific key, for example:

```
order by times->>1
```

Then I get instances ordered like:

```
1. { 1: 100, ... }
2. { 1: 150, ... }
3. { 1: 200, ... }
...
```

And everything is fine, exept query time is about 700 ms

I tried next indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX times_idx ON some_table USING gin(times)
CREATE INDEX times_idx ON some_table USING btree(times)
```

And no one helped. Query time didn't change at all

---

Then, I noticed, that does not metter which operator to use `->>` and `->` - it does no effect to query speed too

---

Big thx for your advices

Comment: what's the time taken without the order by?

Comment: @Nikhil Very good question. 450 ms (with lots of joins and where filters)

Comment: what reduction are you looking for? I think around 500-550 ms will be with any other order by.